# How can I remove a specific request header before sending a request in Chrome or Firefox?

Tags: firefox-extensions, http, google-chrome-extensions

I'm looking for a chrome or firefox extension that would allow me to remove certain 
request headers from all requests to a certain server.

Specifically, I'm trying to disable the browser from sending keep-alive headers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In firefox there are configs you can to turn off the keep alive.

Browse to `about:config` and find `network.http.keep-alive` and set it to false. This will prevent the browser from keeping the connection alive.

See [this page for more info](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.keep-alive).

Answer (score 3):

For sake of completeness:

If you want to do this per-server, you can write a few lines of code that will do it in [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) (CustomRules.js). It's not a Firefox addon, it's a standalone executable which acts like a proxy.

However there are some disadvantages:

- Windows-only
- you have to keep Fiddler open whole time you're browsing
- you have to reset Fiddler's list of connections from time to time, otherwise it will consume memory heavily (Fiddler is meant as a debugging tool primarily, not a background service).